# Linux CMD - How to measure the time for two commands after each other?

Tags: linux, time

I know I can find the time a command takes by just writing *time* before it, such as for

```
time git pull
```

I also know I can do two commands after each other by using the ";" symbol, such as in

```
git pull ; git reset
```

However, I can't figure out how to combine the two.

```
time git pull ; git rebase
```

That just takes the time of the first command and prints it before executing the second. I want to get the combined time of both commands to be printed after both have finished. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use parantheses:

```
# time sleep 1; sleep 1     # <-- this does not work

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
# time (sleep 1; sleep 1)   # <-- this one works

real    0m2.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

I would suggest though to use `&&` instead of `;`, like

```
# time (sleep 1 && sleep 1)
```

This way the second command is only executed when the first one was successful. With `;` both commands are executed no matter what. Just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use paranthesis and && as command separator.

Alternatively you can create a script and

```
time yourscript.sh
```

with the same effect.

You can also do it by measuring the time before and after your operations and computing the difference:

```
start=`date +%s`
sleep 5
end=`date +%s`
runtime=$((end-start))
echo $runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged linux, I'm going to make the wild assumption that you are using the `time` builtin to bash, although most of this answer will be generally applicable to any shell.  In the bash documentation, we read:

*A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&.  The format for a pipeline is:

```
 [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|||&] command2 ... ]*
```

So we see that time is applied to a pipeline, which is made up of commands.  Commands may be compound commands, one form of which is `{ list: }`.  So, for your case, you can write:

```
time { git pull; git rebase; }
```

(Although for this particular case it seems better to do `time git rebase -r`)

Comment: Thanks! The 'case' as it is wasn't actually about git in particular; I just picked the two git commands as easy examples